# Trying to Install Flask - Unmet Package Dependency

Tags: dependencies, python3, flask

I am looking to start messing around with Python Flask and am attempting now to install the packages I need in my 16.10 install. After running 'sudo apt-get install python3-flask' I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-flask : Depends: python3-click but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I looked at my packages in Synaptic out of curiosity and see that I have this python3-click-package installed.

Any suggestions on resolving this?

Comment: Run `apt list --installed | grep python3-click` to check for the package.

Comment: That returns this: python3-click-package/yakkety,now 0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: Could I just install that one missing package manually or will I cause problems for myself that way?

Comment: Yes, you can try to install it manually. Download it from here https://pkgs.org/download/python3-flask

Comment: Yes thank you, that was successful. I didn't realize it would be that simple. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Im glad it worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output from `apt list --installed | grep python3-click`,

```
python3-click-package/yakkety,now 0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

states that the package is installed, you only need the previous dependency: `python3-flask`.

You can manually download and install it from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/python3-flask).